# Sum time intervals in Linq To SQL and C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datetime, sum

I need to sum the hours worked. I have 2 fields: **startTime** and **endTime**. Are "***datetime***" and "***nullable***"

I tried this but it returns error:

```
var timeWorked = res.AsEnumerable()
                    .Sum(f => f.endTime.HasValue ? f.endTime.Value : 0 - f.startTime .HasValue ? f.startTime .Value : 0);
```

**Error**: "Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'"

The above code is in the following context

```
 try
 {                           
     using (serviciosDBDataContext miDataContext = new serviciosDBDataContext("Data Source='xxxxxxx'"))
      {
          var res = (from p in miDataContext.works
                     select new
                      {
                           p.idWork,
                           p.status,
                           p.amount,
                           p.startTime,
                           p.endTime    
                      }).ToList();                                 
//HOURS WORKED

    var timeWorked = res.AsEnumerable()
                        .Sum(f => f.endTime.HasValue ? f.endTime.Value : 0 - f.startTime .HasValue ? f.startTime .Value : 0);       
      }    
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
        MessageBox.Show(AppResources.errCargaEstad);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) and [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651) methods here:

```
var timeWorked = res.AsEnumerable().Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (total, f) => total + (f.endTime.GetValueOrDefault() - f.startTime.GetValueOrDefault());
```

FYI in your example there's a precedence issue, ie the following gets evaluated:

```
f.endTime.HasValue ? f.endTime.Value : (0 - f.startTime.HasValue)
```

Also, there is no implicit conversion between an `int` and a `DateTime`, so the conditional ternary operator cannot succeed.

**Update**

You can access the `TotalMilliseconds`, `TotalSeconds`... [properties of TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties%28v=vs.110%29) to use these values in a method requiring a numeric type, however if you are dealing with time periods, the TimeSpan struct was created specifically for this purpose and mas reasoning about code far easier IMO.

**Update 2**

Okay, based on your comment of hours worked, I'd suggest renaming the variable from `timeWorked` to `hoursWorked` since an int representing a time without a unit given in the name can be misunderstood. The property the you require is [TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.110%29). This returns a `double`, you can explicitly cast to an `int`, however there may be a loss of precision:

```
var hoursWorked = (int)res.Sum(f => (f.endTime.GetValueOrDefault() - f.startTime.GetValueOrDefault()).TotalHours);
```

Also, since you are calling `ToList` to make `res` a list this forces the result into memory, so the call to `AsEnumerable` is unnecessary.

Comment: Returns error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int'"

Comment: @aco Please post the rest of your code - the type of `timeWorked` will be inferred as `TimeSpan`, where are you trying to use it in place of an `int`?

Comment: Ok. I have updated my question. But after var timeworked I have not more code until I fix it sum hours.

Comment: `res.AsEnumerable(). ...` kills performance, at least restrict it by projection.

Comment: But this line --> var timeWorked = res.AsEnumerable().Sum(f => f.endTime.GetValueOrDefault() - f.startTime.GetValueOrDefault());
 returns these errors when I compile: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int'" and this other: "Can not convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func <AnonymousType#1,int>' because some of the return types of the block can not be implicitly converted to the return type of the delegate" (translated with google traductor).

Comment: Tried. But this line: var timeWorked = res.AsEnumerable().Aggregate((total, f) => total + (f.endTime.GetValueOrDefault() - f.startTime.GetValueOrDefault());
                         Returns:  "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnonymousType#7' and 'System.TimeSpan' "

Comment: @aco Apologies, I missed off an argument in the call to Aggregate. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you! Following your answer (update 2) now I get the correct result :) I've changed "TotalHours" for "TotalMinutes" for more precision. SOLUTION:
var minutesWorked = (int)res.Sum(f => (f.endTime.GetValueOrDefault() - f.startTime.GetValueOrDefault()).TotalMinutes);      
var span = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutesWorked);
                        var hours = ((int)span.TotalHours).ToString();
                        var minutes = span.Minutes.ToString();
                        this.lblSumHoras.Text = hours + ":" + minutes ;